# Italicize all equations in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In Word 2010, letters in equations are italicized by default. But after I formatted the document using the Format Painter, equations are not italicized.

Now I want to italicize all equations in the document. Is there a quick way to do so? Alternatively, how can I format-paints a paragraph without changing the format of the equations in the paragraph in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Click **Find**.
2. Click **More**.
3. Press Format and then **Font**.
4. Choose Cambria Math (assuming this is the font used in your
   equations).
5. Press **Find In** -> **Main Document**.
6. You should now have all equations in your document highlighted.
7. Close the dialog and apply the appropriate formatting.